# Calling onPause as a regular function?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have all of my code for updating sharedprefs in my onpause code. In my app onPause does nothing else but save. I want to update shared prefs when I move between activites. Is it ok to call onPause as my saving function instead of duplicating the code into a save() method?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: No..make a new method of saving preferences calls and call that method in `onPause()` and wherever else you need to save the preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add it in `OnPause()` but its good approach add it some methods and call it in `OnPause()` in this way you can call save from other points too you will not limited.

```
void SavingCode() {

        // my Saving code here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        SavingCode();
        super.onPause();

    }
```